# Какая логика задачи?

Tags: физика

На идеально гладкой горизонтальной поверхности неподвижно стоит куб с массой m1. Неподалеку от куба возвышается стена, плоскость которой параллельна одной из боковых граней куба. С противоположной от стены стороны с некоторой скоростью скользит в направлении стены куб с массой m2 ,. Скорость перпендикулярна к стене и боковым граням обоих кубов Все удары абсолютно упругие. Понятно, что после столкновения первый куб начнет скользить в направлении стены, после чего отразится. и, вероятно, еще раз столкнется с другим. Вам нужно определить общее количество столкновений, которые состоятся в системе.

Comment: Что значит какая? Сохранение энергии плюс сохранение импульса - и считай. До тех пор, пока скорость удаления от стены M2 не станет равна или больше, чем скорость M1. Расстояния - игнорируй, ибо не влияют. Начальную скорость бери за единицу.

Comment: Логика очень простая - используя закон сохранения энергии и закон сохранения импульса расписать столкновения тел между собой и стеной для произвольной к-ой итерации, распространить результат к+1 столкновения и устремить к в бесконечность. Исследовать решение для различных соотношений m1 b m2.

Comment: это клон закрытого вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1216688/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9

Answer (score 0):

это забавная задачка - там при определённом подборе масс будет число pi вылезать :)

https://elementy.ru/problems/595/Odnomernyy_bilyard